# Caching queries in mybatis - possible ways

Tags: java, mybatis

I have many queries written in mybatis. What are possible ways to cache answers ?
For example, 
`SELECT * FROM someFun(#{someId})`
or
`SELECT count(*) FROM someFun(#{someId})`

In other words, I search for way which cache only these queries which I would like to cache (something like annotations, maybe?)
Of course, caching should depend on parameters, e.q. the some queries in `XML`, but with different parameters should be newly recomputed,
for example:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM someFun(2) -- compute
SELECT count(*) FROM someFun(2) -- cache
SELECT count(*) FROM someFun(2) -- cache
SELECT count(*) FROM someFun(3) -- compute
SELECT count(*) FROM someFun(2) -- cache
SELECT count(*) FROM someFun(3) -- cache

....
10 minuts
....
SELECT count(*) FROM someFun(3) -- compute
SELECT count(*) FROM someFun(2) -- compute
SELECT count(*) FROM someFun(3) -- cache
SELECT count(*) FROM someFun(2) -- cache
```

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 2):

You can choose which [queries to cache](http://www.mybatis.org/mybatis-3/sqlmap-xml.html#select) as well as interval for when you want your [cache to flush](http://www.mybatis.org/mybatis-3/sqlmap-xml.html#cache).

Both options are documented.
Look for useCache on select and flushInterval on cache

Answer (score 2):

You can use MyBatis 3 cache service. Just add the below tag in your mapper file.

```
<cache/>
```

You can customize the way your cache operates. In your case if you want your cache to flush after 10 minutes add the following code in your mapper file.

```
<cache flushInterval="60000"/>
```

There are other customization options available which you can check at [MyBatis Cache](https://mybatis.org/mybatis-3/sqlmap-xml.html#cache)